# Any good ways to simplify the following logical operation?

Tags: matlab

I am doing the something similar to the following logical operation:

For example, test for `(x,y), x and y` takes values of 0 or 1 only, hence, there are 4 different choices: `(0,0), (0,1), (1,0) and (1,1)`. I want that if `(0,0)` happens, then the program execute `function00`; `(0,1) for function01`; `(1,0) for function10` and `(1,1) for function11`.

Of course, I can use `if then else` to write it, but I guess it is a little bit length to do it.

```
if x==0 && y==0
  'run function00'
  else if x==0 && y==1
    'run function01'
    else if x==1 && y==0
      'run function10'
      else if x==1 && y==1
       'run function11'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The point here is using it-then-else makes the codes to be unreadable. I try to use `switch` to make it more readable in some sense:

```
switch (x,y)
   case (0,0)
     'run function00'
   case (0,1)
     'run function01' 
   case (1,0)
     'run function10'
   case (1,1)
     'run function11'
end
```

However, when I use `switch`, the problem is that there is a syntax error when I set the cases to be `(0,0), (0,1), (1,0) and (1,1)`. I wonder how to fix it, or other operations that I do not know can do the same thing. Could anybody give some suggestions on it? Here, assuming I have defined `function00.m`, `function01.m`, `function10.m` and `function11.m` already.

Comment: How long does it typically take for each of these functions to run? Please be specific... (I'm asking because maybe your code can be vectorized; sometimes it's faster to just compute all 4 options and choose the right one at the end)

Comment: The functions I have can be further grouped into two types according to the computation time: one type requires around 30 sec, while the other type requires around 5 minutes to run. Indeed, in my program, (x,y) takes the value from 0 to 2 for each x and y.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest avoiding `eval` and using function handles instead. Define a cell array of function handles

```
>> fh = cell(2,2); 
>> fh{1,1} = @function00; fh{1,2} = @function01; % And so on for all four elements
>> out = fh{x+1,y+1}(); % Where x y are your binary variables
```

Answer (score 0):

You can construct the string "function"+ x + y on the fly, and use eval to execute that string as a function. This is probably the simplest solution in your case.

```
eval(sprintf('run function%d%d',x,y))
```

Comment: Thanks, I haven't thought about using this.

Also, just for interest, is it possible to write using 'switch', solving the problem?

Comment: switch only accepts ONE scalar or ONE string. So if you are going to use switch, you will need to somehow represent x and y with one quantity. For instance z = sprintf('%d%d',x,y); switch(z); case '00': run function00... I would suggest you stick with the eval solution though, since your function name matches perfectly with x and y; there is no better context to use eval than this.