# calling a matlab function whose name contains a numeric variable

Tags: matlab, function-calls

I have a set of functions such that I want to apply each of them in a separate iteration. I label the functions as:  Strategy1(x), Strategy2(x)....Strategy100(x). As you can see, there is a numeric variable in the name of the function. I want to achieve something like

```
LS = [Strategy1(x),Strategy2(x),...,Strategy100(x)];
Y = zeros(100,1);
for i = 1:1:100
    Y(i) = Strategyi(x);
end
```

I wonder if there is a way to achieve this goal in matlab?

Comment: I highly doubt the design of your script. Why on earth do you need 100 functions? What is so different about them?

Comment: It is actually about 15 functions for each player and I have 2 players. I want to brutal force all 15^2 combinations of there strategies. So I will eventually have to write 2 for loops. And each of these 15 strategies are very different

Comment: This is not the way to do that. You typically define a function that handles the strategies. Numbering function 1 to 15 completely hides what each function is actually doing. This will shoot you in the foot at some point.

Comment: This will be very slow. When I fix the strategy of the pair of player, I need to do very heavy computation that will call the stratagy many times. If I write a very big function and inside the function there are many if or switch conditions, it's gonna make the code very sloww

Comment: Using `eval` is going to make it even slower. MATLAB's JIT compiler will have no idea what the behavior is going to be so it cannot be optimized. Of the two, the "big" `if` or `switch/case` block is a far better option, and even still there's very likely a much better way to do it than either one of those.

Comment: @ftxx Typically, the time gain by obfuscating the code at this high level in the program, is completely lost by being confused later on.

Comment: If you really have to have 100 funtions I would suggest using a cell array of function handles as described in my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39157855/any-good-ways-to-simplify-the-following-logical-operation/39158399#39158399

Answer (score 0):

You could create function handles by using **str2func**

```
n = 100;
Y = zeros(n,1);
for i = 1:n
    funcH =  str2func( sprintf('Strategy%d', i));
    Y(i) = funcH(x);
end
```

If you want to concatenate the function names outside the for loop you could use **srtcat**

```
strcat('Strategy', strread( num2str(1:n), '%s'))
```